# TSQL Joining three tables where none have a common column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

This will probably be pretty simple, as I am very much a novice.

I have two tables I have imported from Excel, and pretty much I need to update an existing table of e-mail addresses based off of the email addresses from the spreadsheet.

My only issue is I cannot join on a common column, as none of the tables share a column.

So I am wondering if, in a Join, I can just put something like

```
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON b.column 'name' = a.column 'nameplus' `
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show some sample data from both tables.

Comment: Your code does not comply with [SQL syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Also you have a mismatch between the title and your explanation about how many tables are involved. So, is it two or three?

Answer (score 1):

A join without matching predicates can be implemented effectively be a `cross join`: i.e. every row in table A matched with every row in table B.

If you specify an `INNER JOIN` then you have to have an `ON` term, which either matches something or it doesn't: in your example you may have a technical match (i.e. `b.column` really does - perhaps totally coincidentally - match `a.column`) that makes no business sense.

So you either have

- a `CROSS JOIN`: no way of linking the tables but the result is all possible combinations of rows

Or:

- an `inner join` where you must specify how the rows are to be combined (or a `left/right outer join` if you want to include all rows from either side, regardless of matched-ness)

Comment: Oh my god...I can't believe I didn't think of cross join.  This is all I needed.  Thank you!  As soon as my "I'm a noob so I have to wait to select the answer" wait time is up I'll select your answer.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @PapaNer - I hope you understand that `CROSS JOIN` explicitly creates `Cartesian product`.